The Internal Clipboard is Empty when copy-pasting material nodes from one material to a new material
I am creating several materials that use the same nodes. I copy the nodes from one material to a new material and I get the error, "The internal clipboard is empty". I do not always get this error. Why does this error happen?


i think blender 4.x still don't support this .
i try to copy paste Geometry node , same issue.
someone talked about this three years ago:https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/94403
four years ago :https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/n5fbbc/?sorting=hot
there is an addon for blender 2.8,which can use on material nodes.
you can try :https://blenderartists.org/t/nodecustombuilder-2-8-free-addon/1152185

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
